# How do I disable cxGrid's internal dbnavigator without hiding it?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

[image]

I have shown the navigator on a `TcxGrid`. I'd like to make the entire navigator disabled without hiding it. How can I do that?

Comment: Which component is this? Is it `TcxGrid` with default properties?

Comment: cxGrid does not have built in dbnavigator by default. You enable it (navigator: True/False). False by default.

Comment: So, if you don't want it enabled, why did you, er, enable it? I think the question is not clear. Do you actually want to control the `Enabled` property of the individual buttons on the navigator?

Comment: for learning's sake ..  :)

Comment: Please can you edit the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: don't know really how to make the question more clear... Enable/disable the built in dbnavigator. Not buttons or anything ...As a whole.

Comment: I rolled the question back. Answers go in answers, not in questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at NavigatorButtons of the view. You can disable/enable every one e.g.

```
view.NavigatorButtons.Append.Enabled := false;
```

or disable/anable them all in a loop:

```
var
 i:Integer;
begin
 for I := 0 to view.NavigatorButtons.ButtonCount - 1 do
   view.NavigatorButtons.Buttons[i].Enabled := false;
end;
```